# How do I create a right aligned logout button?

Tags: html, css

My top div acts as a logo and has a title. I would like a logout button to be on the right-hand side of the div and text above also right-aligned.

I left out the button/ link as i did not know where to place it.
I'm looking for something like this:
[image]

My goal is a logo and, on the right, the logout button with text on the top.
How can I achieve that?

```css
.logo {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: pink;
  color: blue;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <h1>LOGO</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the button?

Comment: I did not know where to place it so i left it out sorry

Comment: `float` will help you out a lot here ... constrain the width of the h1 text and make a div (within div.logo) containing your button -- but float the new div right `div.logout{ float: right; }` again playing with sizes may help

Comment: Just for kicks, [here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/jx783dgt/) using [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox here. Try this out:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #1F6C8B;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>LOGO</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>abcdefg</p>
    <button>Click It</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dm198kpx/2/

Comment: For reference, see [Flexbox @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to achieve what you want. I believe the simplest one is with [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.justify-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex justify-between">
  LOGO
  <div>
    BLABLABLA<br>
    <button>Logout</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, `flex` is a `display` property that is usually used in container-type elements (like `div`). It helps to align content. It allows the use of various other properties like `justify-content`, `align-items`* and others. In this case, we are using only `justify-content`, which align direct children on the main axis (the horizontal one by default), with the `space-between` value, which distributes the content as far as possible - and since we have only two direct children of `<div class="flex justify-between">`, `LOGO` and `<div>`, put the first on the far left and the last on the far right.

*: you can learn more about Flexbox properties and use cases in this game: https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've added the button to what I think is your header? I used the native `header` tag, but if it isn't your header, you can always replace this with a div with a unique id of your choice. I included `position:fixed;` in the css, otherwise the button wouldn't stay to the right (you could use float, but it can be problematic imho). Height/colour etc are adjustable of course.

Hope this helps

```css
h1.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #1F6C8B;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#logout {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  right: 40px;
  position: fixed;
}

.logo,
#logout {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="logo">LOGO</h1>
  <button id="logout">Logout</button>
</header>
```

EDIT: Just saw the text-above edit to your question. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/m2dgL3t4/)

Comment: One possible issue: if the page scrolls, the button will always stay fixed in the same position. [Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/e70Lfjmd/).

Comment: @showdev OP may want to allow the user that option, or use position absolute. choice is up to OP